# I create facebook login app in meta developer with aos but I stuck with the third step

Tags: android

It always show There was a problem verifying this package name. Please check and try again, so I cannot continue to other step:

I try many way like open in different browser, package naming convention

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.